# Как очистить  MS Chart?

Tags: диаграммы, visual-studio

Не могу перерисовать график chart в Visual Studio с новыми данными.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как очистить зону для рисования? Или надо удалять и создавать объект сначала?

Answer (score 1):

Если это .NET C#

```
chart.Series[0].Points.Clear();
```

Comment: Ну, очистили, а перерисовать как?

Answer (score 1):

В цикле:

```
chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(point_X, point_Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

После `chart.Series[0].Points.Clear();` пишите `chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(значение X, значение Y);` и в chart будут новые значения.